# how to solve this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

This is the question in my text :

> A monochromatic light of wavelength $\mathrm{600 \times 10^{-9}m}$ is used in a Young's double slit experiment. One of the slit is covered by a transparent sheet of thickness $\mathrm{1.8 \times 10^{-5}m}$ made of a material of refractive index 1.6 . How many fringes will shift due to introduction of the sheet?

I don't know how to solve the above problem, but i am even not able to understand the solution given in the solution book. Author has written a statement:

> One fringe shifts when the optical path changes by one wavelength.

i am not able to understand this statement also.

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem.

**EDIT**

i don't want the procedure but i want what does that statement mean which author has given.

i also want how to find optical path change.

Comment: why the question has been put "on hold" :(

Comment: http://se.u.94y.info for a list of potentially helpful resources

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).